# Condition to stop the infinite loop of a flow in Power Automate

Tags: loops, sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate

I have the following problem and no clue how to handle it:

an automatically triggered flow should retrieve the content of the attachment field (picture) and transfer the related link to another column in the list "MainList". The attachment field is set to only one item, sometimes in the customized list-form the picture must be manually removed and a new one manually uploaded instead. This flow should then transfer it's link into the "PicLink" column of the source-list:

Flow:

**WHEN AN ITEM IS CREATED OR MODIFIED**

Website: xxxxx

Listname: MainList

**GET ATTACHMENTS**

Website: xxxxx

Listname: MainList

ID: ID

**INITIALIZE VARIABLE**

Name: AttachmentURL

Type: String

Value: first(body('Get_attachments'))?['AbsoluteUri']

**UPDATE ITEM**

Listname: MainList

.....

PicLink: AttachmentURL

---

Flow works fine but runs continuously almost every second and now I was notified that flow will be disabled in a week and now slowed down! I have already found out that I have to include some kind of condition here, but I don't know how? I tried the following in the Trigger-Condition of the first flow-step *WHEN AN ITEM IS CREATED OR MODIFIED*:

@equals(triggerBody()?[‘MyAttchColumn’],null)

Now the flow is triggered when creating a new dataset and also transfers the link, however, it also runs here about a dozen times. But when modifying the attachment field (delete/new) it is no longer triggered. Can anyone help me here? Please no links to Infopages, I even don't know how to customize their tips to my flow. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to a stop condition at the start for the flow. You can do this by

Creating a boolean column in MainList say "UpdatedByFlow" and at the beginning of the flow check if UpdatedByFlow is false then continue with the flow otherwise do nothing.

Under Update Item section set the UpdatedByFlow to true.

Comment: @ Muhammad Obaidullah Ather   Thanks for the reply. **at the beginning of the flow check if UpdatedByFlow is false** =>> as code in the same way like *@equals(triggerBody()?[‘MyAttchColumn’],null)* or by using ifYES/ifNO flow step?

Comment: after the trigger step check using if/else